# Understanding IP and ports in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am quite confused how IPs and ports work in kubernetes.

Here is my yaml for a very basic service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: httpbin-pod
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: httpbin
spec:
  containers:
  - name: httpbin-container
    image: kennethreitz/httpbin
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        name: backend-port

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: httpbin
  ports:
  - name: httpbin-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8090
    targetPort: backend-port
    nodePort: 30001      
  type: NodePort
```

I deploy it on minikube.

So my understaning is that when user sends a request at port 30001, then svc would direct it to httpbin service running at targetPort(ie 8080) in container.

But what ip or host name should I use to access it?
I tried with localhost, minikube ip, and even svc endpoint url. But none works.

Comment: Is `8080` vs. `8090` a typo ?

Comment: targetPort has value 'backend-port' in Service, and backend-port is 8080(containerPort) in Pod.

Comment: How is the question related to `docker`?

Comment: Rmoved docker tag.

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the problem you have here is that the image you're using `kennethreitz/httpbin` listens on port 80 rather than 8080.

If you change the value of  `containerPort: 8080` in the pod definition to `containerPort: 80` that'll work fine in terms of getting the traffic to the node.

You might find minikube's [instructions on service ports](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#getting-the-nodeport-using-the-service-command) useful here as well to get the exact destination.